# Script Interpreter for GWT/AppEngine Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Im interested in providing the user the posibility to write their scripts in the client side in my appengine application. Is this possible?

Basically the script must be storaged in a string to after executing it.

I allready tried with BeanShell, Java Compiler API, Java Scripting API, Groovy and no succes into my Eclipse GWT/AppEngine Project. Thanks!

Comment: What scripts, i.e. what language? What have you tried? What doesn't work?

Comment: The language isn't very importante, i tried BeanShell, Java Compiler API, Java Scripting API, Groovy, but anyone works with appengine in client side. Though, i will look into Rhino as as5wolf said.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using the Mozilla Rhino javascript interpreter in appengine. Works like a charm. Scripts are stored in datastore as string. Rhino even compiles those scripts to genuine java byte code before execution. Out of the box Rhino isn't configured as a secure sandbox. That is, your scripts by default have full access to all the appengine APIs. Rhino allows for fine grained control of what's accessible however.

Comment: I cant find the way to put it into my eclipse appengine project. Could you help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: The OP is clearly asking for a client side interpreter